# How to use Class.getMethod as a getter?

Tags: java, class, methods, reflection, getter

I'm currently trying to use `Class.getMethod` as a getter.

I tried using this method:

```
//This works fine
Class<?> c = Class.forName("Cat");
//This is not working 
Cat cat = c.getMethod("getCat");
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think `getMethod` will return a `Method` and not a `Cat`...

Comment: You're using reflection. Use only if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class Class offers you methods such as

- `newInstance()` to invoke the default constructor
- or `getDeclaredConstructors()`

That way you can create instance objects from Class objects. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html) for the official documentation how to use reflection to create instances.

The **only** way `getMethod()` could possible work is: if there is a parameter less **static** method with that name on the Cat class, then

```
Cat cat = c.getMethod("getCat").invoke(null);
```

might work.

The real answers here:

- when you are newbie, don't *assume* how things might be working. Read the documentation, or a good tutorial
- when you are a newbie: don't use reflection. Reflection can easily drive grown up mature Java programmers crazy. It is really a no-go area for newbies.

Comment: @Leocat You are very welcome. But please please please: dont take "it worked" as proof that you should be working with Reflection. As said: reflection is **really** hard. You **only** use it when you have to. Newbie programmers rarely have a reason to use reflection. There are zillions of other, more important (less hard) things to learn about before turning to reflection in Java.

Comment: Amen to that.  The first rule of using reflection is:  You don’t need reflection.

Answer (score 4):

`getMethod` returns a [`java.lang.reflect.Method`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) object. You then need to invoke it:

```
Cat cat = c.getMethod("getCat").invoke(null);
// Here ------------------------^
```